# SQL query to determine whether it is day or evening

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have here my query and what i wanted to do is how can i determine whether the time of day is Day or Evening in start_time. what would be the condition and sql statement for this. Can you also explain to me how your query works? Thanks.

- Also how am i going to separate the date and the hours in start_time - i want to retain the Date only in the colum
- How am i going to sum up the duration per usr_name

[Image - Selected query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hryd.png)

9:00-17:00 will output Day in data column

17:00-20:00 will output Evening in data column

```
SELECT TOP 10 dt.start_time, ph_e_user.usr_name, dt.e_user, dt.duration
FROM data_transaction dt
LEFT JOIN ph_e_user ON dt.e_user = ph_e_user.code
INNER JOIN data_context dc ON dc.code = dt.data_context
INNER JOIN ct_NO_ICE_OB_Velko ct ON ct.easycode = dc.contact 
WHERE convert (varchar(10),dt.start_time,111) = '2017/03/17'
```

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag since your syntax is clearly SQL Server.

Comment: oh, I'm sorry. Thanks @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: I am defining the start_time column

Comment: you can use case statement in your start_time like when start time between 18:00:00 and 05:00:00 then 'evening' else 'morning'

Comment: @Grinex Is the start_time is datetime data type, which is similar to the GetDate() function ?

Comment: yes it is @RamMehta

Comment: Okay, you can separate the two( time and hour) by the answer I have posted below. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast the `start_time` column to `TIME` type, and then compare it against the two ranges you defined.

```
SELECT TOP 10
    dt.start_time,
    ph_e_user.usr_name,
    dt.e_user,
    dt.duration,
    CASE WHEN CAST(dt.start_time AS time) >= '9:00:00' AND
              CAST(dt.start_time AS time) <= '17:00:00'
         THEN 'day'
         WHEN CAST(dt.start_time AS time) > '17:00:00' AND
              CAST(dt.start_time AS time) <= '20:00:00'
         THEN 'evening'
         ELSE 'unknown'        -- you never specified this case
    END AS label
FROM data_transaction dt
LEFT JOIN ph_e_user
    ON dt.e_user = ph_e_user.code
INNER JOIN data_context dc
    ON dc.code = dt.data_context
INNER JOIN ct_NO_ICE_OB_Velko ct
    ON ct.easycode = dc.contact 
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dt.start_time, 111) = '2017/03/17'
```

If you wanted to sum the duration by username, you could try:

```
SELECT TOP 10
    dt.start_time,
    ph_e_user.usr_name,
    dt.e_user, dt.total_duration
FROM
(
    SELECT e_user, SUM(duration) AS total_duration
    FROM data_transaction dt
    WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dt.start_time, 111) = '2017/03/17'
    GROUP BY e_user
) dt
LEFT JOIN ph_e_user
    ON dt.e_user = ph_e_user.code
INNER JOIN data_context dc
    ON dc.code = dt.data_context
INNER JOIN ct_NO_ICE_OB_Velko ct
    ON ct.easycode = dc.contact
```

Comment: You are asking for two different queries now.  One is what I have given you above, the other is an aggregation.  You should not keep changing your question like this.

Comment: Hi Tim, 2nd answer is parsing successfully but when i applied it to my statement, i keep getting error.
I dont know why, can you show me how to do that on my query statement?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the DATEPART function with the same.

This solves one of the questions which you have asked.

```
SELECT TOP 10 dt.start_time, ph_e_user.usr_name, dt.e_user, dt.duration,
CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, dt.start_time) >= 9 AND
          DATEPART(HOUR, dt.start_time) <= 17
     THEN 'Day'
     WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, dt.start_time) > 17 AND
          DATEPART(HOUR, dt.start_time) <= 20
     THEN 'Evening'
     ELSE 'Bed Time'        -- unknown :) 
END AS DayTime
FROM data_transaction dt
LEFT JOIN ph_e_user ON dt.e_user = ph_e_user.code
INNER JOIN data_context dc ON dc.code = dt.data_context
INNER JOIN ct_NO_ICE_OB_Velko ct ON ct.easycode = dc.contact 
WHERE convert (varchar(10),dt.start_time,111) = '2017/03/17'
```

Comment: Tim's answer for the second one resolves the second question for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the HOUR component of the `start_period`column. Since it's not clear in your example, which value you want to get if it's extactly 5 p.m. you may need to adopt this example:

```
SELECT  TOP 10 dt.start_time, ph_e_user.usr_name, dt.e_user, dt.duration,
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,dt.start_time) BETWEEN 9 AND 16
            THEN 'Day'
            WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,dt.start_time) BETWEEN 17 AND 19
            THEN 'Evening'
            ELSE 'Other'
        END AS PeriodOfDay
FROM data_transaction dt
LEFT JOIN ph_e_user ON dt.e_user = ph_e_user.code
INNER JOIN data_context dc ON dc.code = dt.data_context
INNER JOIN ct_NO_ICE_OB_Velko ct ON ct.easycode = dc.contact 
WHERE convert (varchar(10),dt.start_time,111) = '2017/03/17'
```

Day from 09:00 to 16:59, Evening from 17:00 to 19:59

**EDIT**

If you want to check for weekend too your query should look like this:

```
SELECT  TOP 10 dt.start_time, ph_e_user.usr_name, dt.e_user, dt.duration,
        CASE
            WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY,dt.start_time) IN (7,1) --FOR @@DATEFIRST=7
                THEN 'Weekend' 
            WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,dt.start_time) BETWEEN 9 AND 16
                THEN 'Day'
            WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,dt.start_time) BETWEEN 17 AND 19
                THEN 'Evening'
            ELSE 'Other'
        END AS PeriodOfDay
FROM    data_transaction dt
        LEFT JOIN ph_e_user ON dt.e_user = ph_e_user.code
        INNER JOIN data_context dc ON dc.code = dt.data_context
        INNER JOIN ct_NO_ICE_OB_Velko ct ON ct.easycode = dc.contact 
WHERE   CONVERT(VARCHAR((10),dt.start_time,111) = '2017/03/17'
```

**BE CAREFUL** and check the @@DATEFIRST variable. More on this here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms181598.aspx

Comment: sir, in your query statement. how can i output saturday and sunday as "Weekend"?